# In Jekyll, site.posts returns nothing

Tags: ruby, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I blog with Jekyll. In my `source/index.html` (I reconfigured the paths in `_config.yml`) I have written:

```
{{ site.posts }}
```

But when I compile it it gives no results. I am sure that I have posts, they are compiled and work as supposed.

I don't know where to start troubleshooting, have anyone else had such problem?

Answer (score 1):

site.post returns and array of liquified Jekyll::Post objects. You can check the number of posts by simply writing:

```
{{ site.posts.size }}
```

and you could iterate through them writing:

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
  <li class="post">
    <h1><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jekyll posts need to be in the `_posts` folder to be included in the `{{ site.posts }}` variable.

There's a good chance that you may have simply omitted the underscore in your folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the post time, that it occurs in the past, future posts are not added to the `site.posts`.